# What is the React equivelant of Angulars 'ng-container'

Tags: html, angular, reactjs, dom

Instead of having a div element, I want an element like 'ng-container' in Angular to avoid useless div elements in the DOM.

What is the React equivalent of Angulars 'ng-container' ?

[Explanation of ng-container](https://alligator.io/angular/ng-container-element/)

Comment: Read about this: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `React.Fragment`

```
<React.Fragment>
    "Rest of elements here"
</React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 6):

Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

```
function ChildA() {
  return (
    <h5>Child A</h5>
  );
}

function ChildB() {
  return (
    <h5>Child B</h5>
  );
}

function ChildC() {
  return (
    <h5>Child C</h5>
  );
}
```

**Method-1:**
React Fragments helps to add empty container to wrap list of children inside render method.

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**Method-2**
A common pattern is for a component to return a list of children by wrapping children with any container element **e.g div,p**

```
render() {
  return (
     <div>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Method-3**
There is a new, shorter syntax you can use for declaring fragments.You can use <> the same way you’d use any other element except that it doesn’t support keys or attributes.

```
render() {
  return (
     <>
      <ChildA />
      <ChildB />
      <ChildC />
    </>
  );
}
```

**Method-4**
React 16.0 added support for returning an array of elements from a component’s render method. 
Instead of wrapping the children in a DOM element, you can put them into an array:

```
function App() {
  return (
    [
      <ChildA />,
      <ChildB />,
      <ChildC />
    ]

  );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use empty `<>` tag as well

```
<>
  Rest of markup here
</>
```